# Chessboard possible ways from A to B

Tags: combinatorics, chessboard

How can I calculate the possible ways from point A to point B on a empty 8x8 chessboard while only being allowed to move up and right.

Lets say I have to travel from
x1 = 1, y1 = 1
to
 
x2 = 2, y2 = 2

Then there are 2 possible ways.

But what about
x1 = 1, y1 = 1
to
 
x2 = 8, y2 = 8

Is there some sort of a formula? Something with vectors?

Comment: Hint: You have to move as many times up as the difference of $y$'s is; and you have to move right as many times as the difference if $x$'s is. All the different ways of getting from the starting point to the ending point are just reorderings of these up/right moves.

Comment: $(8+8)!/(8!8!)$

Comment: @daruma If you add eight to $x_1=1$ you get $x_2=x_1+8=9$.

Comment: Somewhat [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2604906/11619).

Comment: And a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2025362/11619)

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen, this is just for the original question to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to make in any case

- $8$ step on the right
- $8$ step up

therefore the number of possible ways is

$$\binom{16}{8}=\frac{16!}{(8!)^2}=\frac{16\cdot 15\cdot 14 \cdot 13 \cdot 12 \cdot 11 \cdot 10\cdot 9}{8\cdot 7\cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot2\cdot 1}=12\,870$$

since once we have chosen the 8 step on the right (or up) the path is completely determined.

Comment: Could it be 7 and 14 instead, what with the player already starting in the corner A1? Right method, in any case.

Comment: @Chessanator In that case we have $\binom{21}{7}=\binom{21}{14}$. What is the corner A1?

Comment: Sorry: I was using chess notation for the bottom left corner. If the player already starts there after zero moves, then there's only seven steps right and seven up, for an answer of $\binom{14}{7}$.
Ambiguity in the question results in a classic off by one error.

Comment: @Chessanator Yes of course!

Comment: What @Chessanator says. On an 8x8 chessboard It is only 7 steps from the leftmost file to the rightmost file (denoted A and H respectively when using algebraic notation). Similarly it is only 7 steps from the 1st row to the eighth.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes I think we had clarified yet that point. Thanks